# Parsing through Links stored in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, screen-scraping

I am trying to parse links stored in my csv file, and then print title for each link. I am having some trouble shoot in the bottom of the code when I try to read links and do parsing to get title of each link.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

contents = []

filename = 'scrap.csv'

with open(filename,'rt') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)

    for row  in data:
        links = row[0]
        contents.append(links) #add each url to list of contents

for links in contents: #parse through each url in the list contents
    url = urlopen(links[0].read())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url,"html.parser")

for title in soup.find_all('title'):
    print(title)
```

I expect the output to be be title in each row printed but I am getting following error
line 17, in 
    url = urlopen(links[0].read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Why are you reading a string. it is already the URL you need.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to Python. Do you any suggestions @satyamsoni

Comment: directly use `url = urlopen(links[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Change url = urlopen(links[0].read()) to url = urlopen(links).read()

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This should work and reduce your overhead as well.

```
import pandas as pd
for link in pd.read_csv('scrap.csv')[0].values:
    url = urlopen(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url,"html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

contents = []

def soup_title():
    for title in soup.find_all('title'):
        title_name = title
        return title_name

filename = 'scrap.csv'

with open(filename,'rt') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)

    for row  in data:
        links = row[0]
        contents.append(links) #add each url to list of contents

for links in contents: #parse through each url in the list contents
     url = requests.get(links)
     soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text,"html.parser")
     brand_info = soup_title()
     print(brand_info)
```